# VBA: how to update timestamp when the result of cells with formulas changes

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to get time stamps to update in an Excel table, depending on the result of a formula that returns "Active" or "inactive" if a current user is in another sheet of the Excel.

I've been trying with `If` formulas and recursive iteration within Excel, but with no results.

I tried to use the `Worksheet_Change()` event with no luck, because it does not fire because the "content" of the cell does not change (because is a formula and does not detect the result).

In summary, what I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

In a table in the column "status" I have a formula that detects if the telephone number of a user exists or not in another sheet of the workbook, if it exists, it will update the column: Entry date, if it does not exist, it should update the column exit date (if the user goes back from inactive to active, it should populate another column, for example: last entry, but it should not reupdate the first entry date).

This is what I've come up so far, but as I've read, it doesn't trigger due to the cell "not changing".

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyData As Range
Dim MyDataRng As Range
Set MyDataRng = Range("A:A")
If Not Intersect(Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Activo" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now
    End If
Target.Offset(0, 3) = Now
End If

End Sub
```

But if I use `Workshheet_Calculate()` I cannot get the cell values that have changed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You will have to check for the cells that the user updated.

Comment: One option might be to use the `Worksheet.Change` event to track when the telephone number was entered, instead of tracking a formula based on the telephone number.

Comment: I cant't manualy update the cells, because the phone numbers in the other sheet are updated from another excel file.

Comment: You can store the current values somewhere (in a hidden column or on another sheet) and use the Calculate event to check the current vs previous values.  Are you using a Table/listobject ?

Comment: That could work, yest, now I'm trying to create a new function that checks all the actives or inactives, that is called directly when Worksheet.change event triggers. Going to give your solution (hidden collumn a try too) Thanks!